# C# Access database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to connect to our database and create a program that reads from the table and takes information to a textbox/label. I'm getting an error:

```
int numberOfRowsFeched = oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet1, "Böcker");
```

ERROR: `InvalidOperationException`

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT Fält2, Fält3 FROM Böcker WHERE Fält2 = " + "'\\" + txt1.Text + "\\'";
            oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            dataSet1.Clear();
                oleDbConnection1.Open();
            int numberOfRowsFeched = oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet1, "Böcker");
            if (numberOfRowsFeched > 0)
            {
                DataTable dt = dataSet1.Tables["Böcker"];
                lbl1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() + " " +
                dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                lbl2.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lbl1.Text = "Boken hittades inte.";
                lbl1.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

New code I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MySQL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\cetin.cigel\\databasbibliotek.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;";
            string SqlString = "SELECT Fält1, Fält2, Fält3 FROM Böcker WHERE Fält2 = ?";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlString, conn))
                {
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fält2", txt1.Text);
                    DataTable dt = dataSet1.Tables["Böcker"];
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string text = string.Format("{0} {1}",
                            dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(0),
                            dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(1));
                        lbl1.Text = text;
                        lbl2.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbl1.Text = "Boken hittades inte.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have just posted the exception type. What was the message and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the tables names, it may be a problem with encoding.
also, you may find this useful : http://www.alinq.org/

and please post all the exception so people can help :)

Comment: This is not really an answer since you don't know the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to open a connection that is still open.

[`OleDbConnection.Open` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.open.aspx)

> `InvalidOperationException`:  The connection is already open.

- use the `using`-statement to ensure that everything gets disposed/closed as soon as possible. You are not closing the connection which is a bad idea when using connection-pooling(default)
- you're trying to acess three fields but only selecting two columns in the query?
- don't concatenate sql queries, use parameters instead:

---

```
string SqlString = "SELECT Fält1, Fält2, Fält3 FROM Böcker WHERE Fält2 = ?";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
{
    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlString, conn))
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fält2", txt1.Text);
        DataTable dt = dataSet1.Tables["Böcker"];
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string text = string.Format("{0} {1}",
                dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(0),
                dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(1));
            lbl1.Text = text;
            lbl2.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(2);
        }
        else
        {
            lbl1.Text = "Boken hittades inte.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you translate the Error? I assume it says "selectcommand.connection property has not been initialized."?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih: Yes: http://unlocalize.com/sv/35324_x0-Connection-property-has-not-been-initialized.html So the connection of the dataadapter is yet not initialized. Use my code and a valid connection-string.

Comment: Look at Tim Schmelter's answer.
You have to give the sql-connection to the OleDBAdapter-Object:
`OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)`

Comment: @janitso: You know that you're trying to acess three fields but only selecting two columns in the query? Therefore i've added a third column `Fält1`.

Comment: I have problem with this line: using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString)) Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand' to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter'

Comment: @janitso: Sorry, copy/paste typo. Corrected in my answer. Of yourse i wanted to initialize a `OleDbDataAdapter`.

Comment: Now the only remaining error is the ConnString. Theres no string,int and so on for ConnString. Its obviously a string but I don't know what its going to contain.

Comment: @janitso: A connection needs always a connection-string. Have a look: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Comment: You should show the code in your question not in your comments. It's not readable. But don't show user/password informations.

Comment: @janitso: Click the edit link below your question, edit the question, then save it again. You can use the code-button to format the code-blocks as described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: `da.Fill(dt);` error at this line, `ArgumentNullException was unhandled.` `Value can not be null.`Heres the connection string `string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\...\\databasbibliotek.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;";`

Comment: @janitso: You should really edit your question. 1.because that's fair, other users also want to have this information when they are willing to help you 2. because it's not readable in the comments 3. because i don't know which code you are currently using 4. because i assume that the connenction-string is not the only problem 5. because i think that the error actually is not raised at `da.Fill(dt);` since `OledbDataAdapter.Fill` does not raise that exception according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.fill.aspx).

Comment: I edited the first post with the new code i am using. Thanks for the help, really appericated!

Comment: Im still having problem with the program, would appericate help. This is for a school project and I don't have so much time left.

Comment: You mind helping me with this? Still have the same problem, I'm trying to solve it but I get no further.

Comment: @janitso: I'm not so familiar with the syntax for ADO.NET in Access. You could try `@` instead: `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fält2", txt1.Text);`.